Why $K_\nabla$ is the same as $K_{\omega_S}$?
Let $G\subset GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a Lie subgroup and let $M$ be a manifold.
Consider $S$ a $G-$structure on $M$ and $\nabla$ a connection compatible with $S$.
We know that if $E=E(P,V)$ is the vector bundle associated to a principle bundle $P$ together with a representation of $\rho:G\to GL(V)$, than there is a linear isomorphism:
$\pi^\bullet:\Omega^k(M,E) \to \Omega^k(P,V)_{bas}$.
More explicitly $\pi^\bullet:= i^{-1}\circ \pi^*$ where $\pi^*$ is the pullback and $i:P \times V \to \pi^*(E)$ is the canonical isomorphism that acts on the fiber $i_p:V \to E_{\pi(p)}$, $v\mapsto [p,v]$.
I'm trying to prove the following:

Lemma For any connection $\nabla$ compatible with the $G-$structure $S$ on $M$,
$K_\nabla\in\Omega^2(M,\mathfrak{g}_S)$ is identified with
$K_{\omega_s}\in\Omega^2(S,\mathfrak{g})_{bas}$ via the isomorphism above
$\pi^\bullet:\Omega^k(M,E) \to \Omega^k(P,V)_{bas}$.

Here the principle bundle connection $\omega_S$ is the restricion to $S$ of $\omega_\nabla\in \Omega^1(Fr(E),\mathfrak{gl}_r)$, the connection form on the frame bundle induced by the connection $\nabla$.
$K_\nabla$ and $K_{\omega_S}$ are the curvatures induced respectively by the connection $\nabla$ and the connection 1-form $\omega_S$.
Any tips on how to do it?
